# Dependencies added to POM.xml file do not show under Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies

I added the following dependency to my POM.xml file but they do not show up under Maven Dependencies

```
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>

<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>

<version>1.2.5</version>

<type>pom</type>
```

```
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>

<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>

<version>1.2.5</version>

<type>pom</type>
```

[image: Maven Dependency Folder]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the contents of the pom you'll see why there is no jar file:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.6/cucumber-java-1.2.6.pom

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  <version>1.2.6</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Cucumber-JVM: Java</name>
  <distributionManagement>
    <relocation>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  </relocation>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

And then looking at `io.cucumber`:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/cucumber/cucumber-java/1.2.6/

```
io/cucumber/cucumber-java/1.2.6

../
cucumber-java-1.2.6-javadoc.jar                   2019-11-09 17:48   1262464      
cucumber-java-1.2.6-javadoc.jar.asc               2019-11-09 17:48       488      
cucumber-java-1.2.6-javadoc.jar.md5               2019-11-09 17:48        32      
cucumber-java-1.2.6-javadoc.jar.sha1              2019-11-09 17:48        40      
cucumber-java-1.2.6-sources.jar                   2019-11-09 17:48    222976      
cucumber-java-1.2.6-sources.jar.asc               2019-11-09 17:48       488      
cucumber-java-1.2.6-sources.jar.md5               2019-11-09 17:48        32      
cucumber-java-1.2.6-sources.jar.sha1              2019-11-09 17:48        40      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.jar                           2019-11-09 17:48    238287      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.jar.asc                       2019-11-09 17:48       488      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.jar.md5                       2019-11-09 17:48        32      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.jar.sha1                      2019-11-09 17:48        40      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.pom                           2019-11-09 17:48      6052      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.pom.asc                       2019-11-09 17:48       488      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.pom.md5                       2019-11-09 17:48        32      
cucumber-java-1.2.6.pom.sha1                      2019-11-09 17:48        40
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I import "cucumber.io.junit.Cucumber;" instead of "cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;". I tired that, but no success

Comment: No. I answered your question. However you have other problems too. Try to start from scratch. Follow the tutorial: https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a problem with version 1.2.6 only. I tried a few older versions and they seem to show up under Maven dependencies. Will have a look into this. For now my project has worked with version 1.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `type` to `pom`, you do not import the JAR, but only the dependencies inside the POM you reference.

If you want to use the JARs, you need to change the `type` to `jar`.

Comment: I tried that, it works for <version>1.2.5</version>, but does not seem to work for <version>1.2.6</version>

Comment: Sometimes you might only find the POM in the repository. But without the JAR, it usually makes no sense to use the version

Comment: I got the dependency from the maven repository so its a bit surprising that it does not have a jar file. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: Find it in a different Maven repository or use a different version.